# Is there a way to share torrent downloads between users in a same PC?

Tags: windows-7, utorrent

I'm running uTorrent under Windows 7 Ultimate and I was wondering if there's a way to get uTorrent to download the same torrents for each user in the computer. For instance, let's say I start downloading a torrent and then log off, and then another user logs in. I want that user to resume my download when he starts uTorrent. I tried to do this by saving all .torrents to a shared folder and then setting it up so it automatically loads .torrents from that shared folder. However, since once they are being downloaded they're replaced by .loaded files, this isn't working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run µTorrent in [portable mode](http://www.utorrent.com/help/faq/installation#faq4):

> **How can I make µTorrent run self-contained in one directory?**
>
> Simply copy the entire contents of %AppData%\uTorrent into the same folder as utorrent.exe. Alternatively, create a blank file named settings.dat in the same folder as utorrent.exe

You can copy the settings to `C:\Program Files\uTorrent`, just make sure to give users "Modify" permission on the directory.

Answer (score 2):

You could try running µTorrent [as a service](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/137890) and then using the web interface to administer it. This actually works, I've tried it.

Comment: Running such programs as *LocalSystem* account is terribly insecure (in fact, much worse than *Administrator*). The method is acceptable if used with a dedicated µTorrent user account.