# My torrents are shared between users

Tags: windows-7, utorrent

Since I reinstalled µTorrent I noticed that all my torrents are shared between all users – exactly [like in this question](https://superuser.com/questions/301210/is-there-a-way-to-share-torrent-downloads-between-users-in-a-same-pc).

The problem is, unlike in the question above, I don't want this, and I don't know how undo it.

How can I disable that?

Comment: Was there an All Users or Just for Me option when you installed? If so uninstall and reinstall with the Just for Me option.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the folders you are using in preferences. Just make sure they're your user folders, where by default other users have no access. If they do, then check permissions on that folder, and remove them if they are set.